# ERROR In USING SIGNED IMAGE USING SECURITY BOOTLOADER

Tags: openssl

Could not open file or uri for loading private key from .\Secure_bootloader/Key\priv_key_2048.pem
6C400000:error:16000069:STORE routines:ossl_store_get0_loader_int:unregistered scheme:crypto\store\store_register.c:237:scheme=file
6C400000:error:80000002:system library:file_open:No such file or directory:providers\implementations\storemgmt\file_store.c:267

Comment: So... what's the question ? The error is pretty self-evident. That file, `.\Secure_bootloader/Key\priv_key_2048.pem` ,  either cannot be found, or cannot be opened. Judging by the "No such file or directory", I'm going with the former of those.

Comment: store_get0_loader_int:unregistered scheme:crypto\store\store_register.c:237:scheme=file.... I am not able to understand this error. Is it something to do with openssl?

Comment: That is the location in the openssl source code where the error point was discovered. `error:80000002` effectively means file-not-found. As I said before, the overall error message is that the named file *cannot be found*, at least at the time the code was running and attempted to do so.